# If $f(x)=\mu x-\sin x, x>0$ an is monotonically increasing function. Then find $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

$$f(x)=\mu x-\sin x, x>0 \text{ an is monotonically increasing function.Then,}$$

$$(a)\mu > -1 \quad (b)\mu < -1 \quad (c)\mu > 1 \quad (d)\mu < -1$$

Solution:

$$f(x)=\mu x-\sin x\Rightarrow f'(x)=\mu - \cos x$$

Now, $f(x)$ an is monotonically increasing function.

$${f'(x)>0\\\Rightarrow \mu - \cos x>0\\\Rightarrow \mu > \cos x}$$

Now, $\cos x>-1; \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

i.e. $\mu > \cos x>-1$. So, $\mu>-1$

But, I find these counter examples.

[image]

Where I am wrong?

Comment: The maximum value of $cos(x)$ is 1 so you want $\mu>1$.

Comment: $\mu>-1\iff\mu>\cos(-\pi)$  but $\mu>-1$ does not imply $forall x>0,\mu>\cos x.$ The latter is equivalent to $\forall y\in[-1,1],\mu>y,$ i.e. to $\mu>1.$

Comment: In my opinion the correct answer should be $\mu\ge 1.$ The derivative may vanish, as long as it does not vanish on an interval.

Comment: for $a>b(x)$, $a$ should be greater than maximum value of $b(x)$, Not just the minimum one..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you want
$$\mu-\cos x>0\quad \forall x$$
and in order to ensure that, you need to use the largest possible value of $\cos x$ (rather than the smallest). My reasoning would be
$$\mu-\cos x\geq \mu -1>0 \implies \mu>1 $$

Answer (score 3):

You found correctly that $f'(x) > 0 \iff \mu > \cos x$. If $f$ is monotonically increasing, then $\mu > \cos x$ for all real $x$. This is only true if $\mu > 1$.

It's also true that $$\mu > \cos x \implies \mu > \cos x \geq -1 \implies \mu > -1$$

but the added inequality in between is looser than necessary.

Since the question says just "then" instead of "if and only if", both (a) and (c) could be considered "correct". But neither answer describes the exact set of $\mu$ where $f$ is increasing: that's true if and only if $\mu \geq 1$. $f(x) = x - \sin x$ is also monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f$ is a smooth function, thus for it to be monotonically increasing we require that $f'(x) \ge 0 \ \forall x$, in particular $f'(0) = \mu -1 \ge 0$, which gives the desired result

Comment: @AnneBauval, this does provides an answer, note that $x - \sin(x)$ is also monotonically increasing

Comment: @AnneBauval, The question demands us to provide a condition on $\mu$ it doesn't want us to calculate exactly what is the set of all $\mu$, thus if we can do so by calculating $f'(0)$ I don't see any problem with it in rigor, plus your assumption on derivative to be strictly positive is actually wrong